# Waiting for multiple HTTP requests JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make 3 requests to an API and then populate the array "pics" with the image URLs from each JSON response. Everything works fine but due to the asynchronous nature of JS when I return or print the array of URLs it is empty. How can wait until all 3 image URLs to have been added to the array before returning it? I am aware of js promises and async/await but I haven't had much luck getting those to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getPics(){

let json = "";
let pics = [];

for(i=0; i<3; i++){

  var fetch = new FetchStream(someUrl);

  fetch.on("data", function(chunk){
      json = JSON.parse(chunk);
      pics[i] = json.primaryImageSmall;
});

}

console.log(pics);

};

getPics();
```

Comment: make your function asynchronous, (prefix it with an async keyword), and *await* anything you need to wait for. i.e. `async function fn() { await fetch(someUrl); await fetch(anotherUrl);}`

Comment: I'd try with async/await, here's a great guide on this topic https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: for loops are not asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Promises for that.

```js
// Create each stream (in for loop or whatever)
const a = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
const b = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2');
const c = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3');

// Then wait for all of them to resolve
Promise.all([a, b, c]).then((res) => console.log(res))
```

Check for doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: This would be the ideal solution for queue/task handling of many processes at once.